# Importing Dynamic Variables Between Multiple Python Files Within a Loop

Tags: python, loops, variables, import, python-import

I am sorry if this question is basic, but I have been trying to solve this problem for some time now and cannot figure my way around it.

What I would like to do is have two (or possibly more) python files files -- each taking the concerned input variable(s) from the other and processing them as designed before passing them back to act as the input variable(s) for the other other in a potentially infinite loop.

It's a bit hard for me to adequately articulate with words, so hopefully the very rough mock-up below can act as example.

One.py:

```
while(Status == Active):
     InfoUpdate = input()

     import Two
     varOut = Two.varOut

     if(varOut == "Done"):
          Status = "Inactive"
     if(varOut == "Not Done"):
          Status = "Active"
```

Two.py:

```
import One
InfoUpdate = One.InfoUpdate

if(InfoUpdate == "Continue"):
     varOut = "Not Done"

if(InfoUpdate == "Stop"):
     varOut = "Done")
```

I apologize for any general errors in this example -- I am very new to import operations in general. Please help if you can -- thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is alright to ask basic questions here. The answer to your question is to use a different python script, and storing all your shared variables inside the new script. Here is what has to be done

```
#config.py
InfoUpdate = "none"
varout = "none"
#One.py
import config
while(Status == Active):
     config.InfoUpdate = input()
     import Two
     if(config.varOut == "Done"):
          Status = "Inactive"
     if(config.varOut == "Not Done"):
          Status = "Active"
#Two.py
import config
import One
if(config.InfoUpdate == "Continue"):
     config.varOut = "Not Done"

if(config.InfoUpdate == "Stop"):
     config.varOut = "Done")
```